# Facebook HTML5 Like Button Implementation Returning Error on Like & Unlike

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've read loads and loads regarding this problem, and I'm still stumped.

I'm testing using the HTML5 like button and the Javascript SDK. Everything's working as expected, except that the like button is generating an error, both on like and unlike. The error is:

> The app ID "104975899017" specified within the "fb:app_id" meta tag
>   was invalid.

I've set the correct app ID (yes, I know what an app is) in the SDK initialization code and the Facebook meta tag.

A couple app settings that people seem to think helped them solve the problem:

> App Domain: store.youngdisciple.com, youngdisciple.com,
>   blog.youngdisciple.com Website: http://youngdisciple.com/

Here is the Javascript for the [testing page](http://youngdisciple.com/facebook/fb-share-detect.html) I have:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '130960927011182', // App ID
        channelUrl : '//www.youngdisciple.com/library/FacebookChannel.aspx', // Channel File
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // CUSTOM LISTENING CODE

    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
        function(response) {
            alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
        }
    );
    FB.Event.subscribe('message.send',
        function(response) {
            alert('You sent the URL: ' + response);
        }
    );
};

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));
```

And the meta:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Test"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://s3.pirillo.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/MonitorLight.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://youngdisciple.com/facebook/fb-share-detect.html"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Young Disciple Ministries"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="We are testing..."/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="130960927011182"/>
```

And the button itself:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.youngdisciple.com" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error on like is:

> The app ID "104975899017" specified within the "fb:app_id" meta tag was invalid.

The meta data located on http://www.youngdisciple.com shows

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youngdisciple.com

So I'd say fix the app_id on the home page

Comment: Oh, wow! I was really barking up the wrong tree! Thank you so much for the help!! =D